# What is the expected behaviour of "local +x" in a function with an exported variable in zsh vs bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

In the example below, I have an exported variable. The name is re-used as a local in a function. Inside the function is a child process that uses the ENV variable with the same name.

Bash re-uses the original exported value, while zsh unsets the variable:

```
function the_func {
  local +x  MY_VAR="new value"
  my -child -process  # === in zsh:  $MY_VAR is undefined
                      # === in bash: $MY_VAR="original"
}

export MY_VAR="original"
the_func
```

Is this a bug in zsh or in bash? Or just minor differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is the proper behaviour in both. Zsh ignores the "+x" when using local. From the manual: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

```
local [ +-LRZilrtu [n]] [ name[=value] ]
Same as typeset, except that the options `-x' and `-f' are not permitted
```